Interesting conjecture that I came up with about weighted matchings
I thought of this conjecture while doing this homework, but didn't prove it (I found a way around it in my homework)
Let $n$ be a positive integer. Let $G = U\sqcup V$ be a weighted bipartite graph where $|U| = n+1$ and $|V| = n$. The weight of edge $(u,v)$, denoted $c_{u,v}$, is nonnegative, satisfying

For all $v\in V$, $\sum_{u\in U} c_{u,v} = 1$
For all $u\in U$, $\sum_{v\in V} c_{u,v} \le 1$

Let $m$ be the minimum positive weight. Can it happen that $\sum_{v\in V} c_{u,v} > 1-m$ for all $u\in U$?
An equality case is $m = \frac{1}{n+1}$ and $c_{u,v} = \frac{1}{n+1}$. There are many other equality cases. In particular for the conjecture to be true we must have $m > \frac{1}{n+1}$.

Here is one possible construction for $n=9$, in the form of a $9\times 10$ matrix (with zeroes omitted):
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0.2 & 0.2 & 0.2 & 0.2 & 0.2 \\
0.4 & 0.4 & & & & & & 0.2 \\
& & 0.4 & 0.4 & & & & & 0.2 \\
& & & & 0.4 & 0.4 & & & & 0.2 \\
0.3 & 0.3 & & & & & 0.4 \\
& & 0.3 & 0.3 & & & & 0.4 \\
& & & & 0.3 & 0.3 & & & 0.4 \\
& & & & & & 0.3 & 0.3 & & 0.4 \\
& & & & & 0.2 & 0.2 & & 0.3 & 0.3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The minimum positive weight is $0.2$, but all column sums are $0.9 > 1 - 0.2$.
Another, smaller example for $n=5$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1/2 & 1/2 \\
& & 1/2 & 1/2 \\
& & & & 1/2 & 1/2 \\
1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3 \\
& & & 1/3 & 1/3 & 1/3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
